# How can I let the useEffect run only when its parameter change?

Tags: reactjs, use-effect

The useEffect run in the first and when the parameter change is run another one, I don't want the use effect run until the parameter change only. How?

Comment: Do you want to skip `useEffect` on very first render, do I understand you right?

Comment: Yes, i want that

Comment: If the initial value of the parameter change is always the same, then add a if case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use hook like this to check it's first mount/render

```
const useDidMountEffect = (func, deps) => {
    const didMount = useRef(false);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (didMount.current) func();
        else didMount.current = true;
    }, deps);
}
```

Next you can check result ot `useDidMountEffect`